# folder to locate the pop up $error message in this code

Tags: php, error-handling, error-reporting

I need to edit the error that shows if a user enters an amount below minimum but I can't find the file to edit the pop-up error response that shows if the amount I less than the withdrawal limit.

Here is the code.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="card-title">withdrawal -
          <small class="category">Cash Out Fund.</small>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-icons nav-pills-primary nav-stacked" role="tablist">
              <li class="active">
                <a href="#withdraw" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                  <i class="material-icons">redeem</i>Withdraw
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="withdraw">
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                  <span class="text-center">Please Read before you proceed. You need to know processing fee:</span><br> @php $id=0;@endphp @foreach($gateways as $gateway) @php $id++;@endphp
                  <span>{{$id}}. <b>@if($gateway->name){{$gateway->name}}@endif @if($gateway->local_name){{$gateway->local_name}}@endif</b> we would charge you <b>{{config('app.currency_symbol')}} {{$gateway->fixed}}</b> fixed + <b>{{$gateway->percent}}%</b> to Withdraw.</span>                  @endforeach
                </div>
                <form action="{{route('userWithdraw.post')}}" method="post">
                  {{ csrf_field() }} @if(count($errors) > 0)
                  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-with-icon" data-notify="container">
                    <i class="material-icons" data-notify="icon">notifications</i>
                    <span data-notify="message">
                                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                                        <li><strong> {{$error}} </strong></li>
                                                    @endforeach

                            </span>
                  </div>
                  <br> @endif
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                      <div class="form-group label-floating">
                        <select class="selectpicker" name="gateway" data-style="btn btn-warning btn-round" title="Select Withdraw Gateway" data-size="7">
                          @if($gate->status == 1)
                          <option value="1000">{{$gate->name}}</option>
                          @endif @foreach($gateways as $gateway)
                          <option value="{{$gateway->id}}">{{$gateway->name}}</option>
                          @endforeach
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                      <div class="form-group label-floating">
                        <label class="control-label" for="account">Your PayPal</label>
                        <input id="account" name="account" type="text" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                      <div class="form-group label-floating">
                        <label class="control-label" for="amount">Withdraw Amount</label>
                        <input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

I need to edit all error response that pops up in the file and any other error response on the entire website.

Comment: Any other error response on the entire website. 

Comment: No, don't worry. I was able to locate error response from "app controller" customized all response I needed.

Comment: It wasn't  a script error message. Needed to edit custom error response in the entire website.  Example; "wrong password format error" "wrong password error" "invalid email error" "error didn't reach minimum withdrawal" "error complete KYC" etc.........I needed custom words not a script bug error.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand the question. But I have solved my issue. Thanks all....